# Thingsboard deployment in a Cloud

Tags: deployment, iot, thingsboard

I am starting a venture so that my future customers can have a Dashboard that shows indicators of IoT devices in the cloud.  I have found Thingsboard, which has Apache 2.0 license, so, in theory, I could deploy it in a Cloud, and also change its logo and colors for my company or my clients.

Could someone give me some advice or have experience of deployment with this platform ?

Thanks !

For the moment, it is still very expensive for me to offer the Thingsboard Cloud service to my customers (https://thingsboard.cloud/home).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with ThingsBoard Professional Edition (PE), which requires a license subscription.

The White-Labeling Feature is exactly what you are looking for:

https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/user-guide/white-labeling/

Comment: Thank you. I had already seen that alternative as well, however it is too costly for my venture. Maybe for later, for version 2.